# After a domain name expired and goes into a grace period, what happens to the WHOIS information on it?

Tags: domains, domain-registrar, whois

I have a domain name that is expiring in a few weeks. I want to delete the domain name right now, but the Registrar company will only let me delete it by letting it expire. I have purchased a WHOIS protection that hides my contact information on the domain name.

If I let my domain name (along with the WHOIS protection) expire and it goes into a grace period, will my WHOIS contact information still be on it?

Comment: It depends on the domain name registry/NIC. Do you want to tell us the top-/second-level domain?

Comment: it's a .com domain name, and it's registered with namecheap.

Comment: If you are too curious about your information, and you no longer want your domain name then simply [change those details](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/305/46/how-do-i-change-the-contact-information-for-my-domain) to something else.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, it does depend somewhat on who is the registrar and if your site is hosted. During the reactivation period the WHOIS information will not change because you have the option to renew. Once expired you no longer "own" that domain the registrar will be listed in the WHOIS directory (which is typically what happens when you have privacy protection like you described.)  For example, you can have a registered domain, mydomain.net, that is hosted by Bluehost and if you check the WHOIS it will show bluehost information in the WHOIS record. When mydomain.net is again available for auction, the registrar will be shown in WHOIS. In this example that would be Bluehost.

Comment: Showing new data in whois, like registrar info, past expiration is in no way a standard or automatic change, so it depends on the provider.

Answer (score 1):

Your information will not show, which seems to be your question.

Once the domain expires, either the privacy info will still show on the Whois record or the privacy information will be replaced by some other generic "expired domain" whois information.

Comment: This certainly depends on the registrar and is not a generic rule.